# Select route depends on URL parameter. Constraints

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, routes

First of all, I need to say that I'm using T4MVC in my project. I have one method for two routes :

```
public virtual ActionResult List(string slug, string category, String selectedFilters)
```

Routes:

```
routes.MapRoute("ProductOnSale", "products/{slug}/{category}/onsale", MVC.Product.List());
routes.MapRoute("ProudctsList", "products/{slug}/{category}/{selectedFilters}", MVC.Product.List()
                .AddRouteValue("selectedFilters", ""));
```

As you can see, this is only one `ActionResult` for two routes. They have a different url. Example for the first route:

```
products/living-room-furniture/sofas/sectional-sofa
```

Example for the second route:

```
products/living-room-furniture/living-room-tables/onsale
```

This piece should say that I came from the another page. I need to add Boolean parameter to my method `List(string slug, string category, String selectedFilters, bool onsale)` and, depends on that, choose route. Is it possible to do using constraints? May anyone provide an example how to do it in this case?

Comment: What about creating 2 actions with parameteres for your 2 situations and inside that actions to call a function (with 4 parameters) that return the list of products?

Comment: Of couse, this variant is possible. But is it a good solution in general?

Comment: As long you don't write *duplicate* code, from my opinion it's an **simple** acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if I understand your question correctly. Two cases I come accross might help you.

CASE 1 : redirect to another URL depending on the URL used to access the page.

STEP 1: Create an MVCRouteHandler

public class LandingPageRouteHandler : MvcRouteHandler
{
    protected override IHttpHandler GetHttpHandler(RequestContext Context)
    {
        if (  Context.HttpContext.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost.ToLower().Contains("abc"))
        {
            Context.RouteData.Values["controller"] = "LandingPage";
            Context.RouteData.Values["action"] = "Index"; 
            Context.RouteData.Values["id"] = "abc";
        }
        return base.GetHttpHandler(Context);
    }
}

STEP 2: Add a RouteHandler

```
          routes.MapRoute(
                name: "Landingpage",
                url: "Landingpage/{id}/{*dummy}",
                defaults: new { controller = "Landingpage", action = "Index" }
            );

routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
).RouteHandler = new LandingPageRouteHandler();
```

CASE 2 : Add a property to a controller and view depending on the url used

All controlles in my case derive from a BaseController class. In the BaseController I have :

```
protected override void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext filterContext)
{
    base.OnActionExecuting(filterContext);

    //Set TenantByDomain
    var DnsSafeHost = filterContext.HttpContext.Request.Url.DnsSafeHost;
    int? TenantByDomain = null;
    if (db.Tenants.Any(x => x.DnsDomains.Contains(DnsSafeHost)))
    {
        TenantByDomain = db.Tenants.First(x => x.DnsDomains.Contains(DnsSafeHost)).Id;
    }
    ((BaseController)(filterContext.Controller)).TenantByDomain = TenantByDomain;
    filterContext.Controller.ViewBag.TenantByDomain = TenantByDomain;
}
```

Applied to your Question. 
Using the routehandler you could add an extra property indicating the original route taken and redirect both to a 3th url (! the user does not see this new url).

In the OnActionExecuting do something with the extra routevalue so that the handling can be done as desired.